# ACTION_PICK select no image

Tags: android

In my app I allow a user to select an image as a background, but they also have the option of not selecting an image and using the default. I'm having good luck with using `Intent.ACTION_PICK` and allowing the user to select an image. But I want them to have the ability to later change their minds and select no image. Is it possible to do this with `ACTION_PICK`? Or do I need to have a separate "Clear image" button?

To be clear, if the user cancels, I want to continue using whatever choice they had before.

As a corollary, I'm using extras to `ACTION_PICK` like `aspectX` and `aspectY` which I lifted from other StackOverflow answers, but I can't find any real documentation on them. Is there a list somewhere of extras that most image pickers accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this with ACTION_PICK?

Only if you want to consider `RESULT_CANCELED` to mean "use the default picture" as opposed to "no, I do not want to change the picture".

> To be clear, if the user cancels, I want to continue using whatever choice they had before.

Then you need a separate button or the equivalent (action bar item, gesture, etc.).

> I can't find any real documentation on them

That is because they are undocumented.

> Is there a list somewhere of extras that most image pickers accept?

The list is the empty set. Do not rely on any undocumented extras being supported on any given device.

Comment: I was hoping for a better answer, but I'm not surprised. Thanks